# Hide and show select option based on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys any help will be appreciated. I'm trying to show a set of select option base on what is selected on another select option. I have a select option called "children" with a set of other select option which should be hidden by default. If "1" children is selected then one of the other select option should show, if "2" children is selected then two of the other option should be displayed. I have been trying to get this to work for a few days now with no luck. Can someone point me in the right directions thanks.

here is my html

```
<select name="child" class="form-control" id="numchds" onchange="updateRooms();">
    <option value="child" selected="selected">Children</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div class="row" id="childage">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label for="child">Child 1</label>
        <select name="0" class="form-control" id="chd1age">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label for="child">Child 2</label>
        <select name="child" class="form-control" id="chd2age">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label for="child">Child 3</label>
        <select name="child" class="form-control" id="chd3age">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label for="child">Child 4</label>
        <select name="child" class="form-control" id="chd4age">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label for="child">Child 5</label>
        <select name="child" class="form-control" id="chd5age">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my javascript

```
$('#numchds').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val();
if (val === 'child') {
    $('#chd1age').hide();
    $('#chd2age').hide();
    $('#chd3age').hide();
    $('#chd4age').hide();
    $('#chd5age').hide();

} else if (val === '1') {
    $('#chd1age').show();
    $('#chd2age').hide();
    $('#chd3age').hide();
    $('#chd4age').hide();
    $('#chd5age').hide();
} else if (val === '2') {
    $('#childage').show();
    $('#chd1age').show();
    $('#chd2age').show();
    $('#chd3age').hide();
    $('#chd4age').hide();
    $('#chd5age').hide();
} else if (val === '3') {
    $('#childage').show();
    $('#chd1age').show();
    $('#chd2age').show();
    $('#chd3age').show();
    $('#chd4age').hide();
    $('#chd5age').hide();
} else if (val === '4') {
    $('#childage').show();
    $('#chd1age').show();
    $('#chd2age').show();
    $('#chd3age').show();
    $('#chd4age').show();
    $('#chd5age').hide();
} else {
    $('#childage').show();
    $('#chd1age').show();
    $('#chd2age').show();
    $('#chd3age').show();
    $('#chd4age').show();
    $('#chd5age').show();
}
```

});

Link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BMcJ9/

Comment: Wow, these are always fun when you see them!  Use classes, or the `:not` selector, rather than specifically listing all of these `.show()` and `.hide()` calls!  Challenge: make it so there is *only one* .show() and *only one* .hide for the *entire* function.

Comment: Duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497728/hide-show-the-selected-option-on-a-secondary-select) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579532/show-hide-select-options-based-on-previous-selection-dropdown-in-jquery-or-javas) and there are more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter I made it, work it does

```
$('#numchds').change(function () {
    var val = this.value,
        sel = $('.form-control').not(':first');

    sel.each(function() {
        $(this).add($(this).prev()).toggle(sel.index(this) < val)
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/BMcJ9/4/)

Comment: Thansk guys for the prompt respons adeneo what i need is for child 1, chid 2 etc to be hidden when the page is loaded at first

Comment: @Nakhul - Oh my, that's my mistake, let me fix that  for you dear sir. Look at the answer now sir, is it what you want?

Comment: @Nakhul - Feel free to accept the answer at any time !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#numchds').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val() || 5;
    $('#childage > div').show().eq(val-1).nextAll().hide();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BMcJ9/3/)